# Spring deserialize YAML as LinkedHashMap instead of ArrayList

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, jackson

I observe a difference between the Spring deserialization and a custom deserialization using a simple ObjectMapper.

`application.yml:`

```yaml
props:
 array:
 - name: foo1
   bar: bar1
 - name: foo2
   bar: bar2
```

In the properties file above, when we deserialize "props" as a generic Map (and not a user defined object), we observe that :

- props become an instance of a `LinkedHashMap`
- array become an instance of a `LinkedHashMap` which is incorrect

If we read the properties above with a `new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())`, then we have the expected behaviour, where array is an instance of `ArrayList`.
We also got the expected result if we map the properties to a real Object, with an `List` as target for the `array` property.

I fail to understand the Spring deserialization mecanism, it looks like Spring does not use the ObjectMapper bean to deserialize (I override the Bean it changes nothing).

**Which class to use/override to change the deserialization ?**
I looked at Spring core converters, without success...

BTW, in my mind this looks like a Spring bug. (Spring 5.3.21, Java 17)

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Not sure I follow... You do have key/value pairs so why should it be a list? I believe that if you map them to a class, you will get a list of Object if the object is defined but, if not, LinkedHashMap seems correct to me.

Comment: You are right if you consider that YAML format attachs importance of where the "-" is placed, which is not the case from what I know. The "-" could be in front of any field of the pointed object, here "name" or "bar", without any incidence.

Comment: I also should precise that Spring even not use the filed "name" has key of its generated map ; it generates key "0" and "1" which totally incorrect.

Comment: @grekier please see my answer below for an explanation on why interpreting the key/value pairs in the Yaml as a map is incorrect. The key point is that if you manually parse the same Yaml in code, the returned result is correct: the value for the `"array"` property comes back as an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know good solution with overriding Spring deserialization.

But I created setter method in `@ConfigurationProperties` class for my generic Map props.
And in this method I manually convert needed maps to arrays if all keys in map are sequence "0", "1", "2", ...
And don't forget about using recursion if you can have inner complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have observed this and genuinely believe this is some kind of bug in the  configuration loader as it provides different results for configuration coming from file vs manual loading via `Yaml.load(...)` method.

In case it isn't clear, the Yaml given in the example has the following JSON equivalent:

```json
{
  "props": {
    "array": [
      { "name": "foo1", "bar": "bar1" },
      { "name": "foo2", "bar": "bar2" }
    ],
  }
}
```

And if the Yaml were loaded directly to an `Object` the resulting type tree would be:

```
result: HashMap
> "props": HashMap
  > "array": ArrayList
    > [0]: HashMap
    > [1]: HashMap
```

However, as observed, when the same is loaded as Spring Boot config, it has the following JSON equivalent:

```json
{
  "props": {
    "array": {
      "0": { "name": "foo1", "bar": "bar1" },
      "1": { "name": "foo2", "bar": "bar2" }
    },
  }
}
```

and creates the following Java object:

```
result: HashMap
> "props": HashMap
  > "array": HashMap
    > "0": HashMap
    > "1": HashMap
```

This is particularly clunky if you have code that relies on weakly defined, non-type mapped definitions that can originate either from config file or from an external, at-runtime provided source.

To get around this I use this simple utility function:

```java
public static List<Map<String,Object>> getEntryListFromEntry(Object entry) {
    if(entry == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    if(entry instanceof ArrayList) {
        return ((ArrayList)entry).stream().map(e -> (Map<String,Object>)e).toList();
    }
    Map<String,Object> entryMap = (Map<String,Object>)entry;
    return IntStream.range(0,entryMap.size())
        .mapToObj(n -> (Map<String,Object>)entryMap.get(String.valueOf(n)))
        .toList();
}
```

And for the provided example it would be used something like this:

```java
Map<String,Object> props = // ... loaded by config some way
ArrayList array = getEntryListFromEntry(props, "array");
```